# Rewrite Rule for specific domain without specific directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

We have multiple shops on our server and are now trying to set one shop offline, but still allow our it to access the backend.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)olddomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)olddomain\.de\/backend\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.newdomain.de [L,R=301]
```

But we still get redirected to www.newdomain.de, when trying to access www.olddomain.de/backend/.
How can we establish this, without setting a rewriterule for each and every shop.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Line 1 is always www.olddomain.de, not olddomain.de with or without www.
- Line 2 isn't a HTTP_HOST header, it's a URI.
- Line 3 isn't passing the URL to the new domain

Try changing it to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So that now reads

> If the host is either www.olddomain.de or olddomain.de, and the requested URI doesn't begin with /backend, optionally followed by further URI details, then rewrite the host from olddomain.de to www.newdomain.de and pass the requested URI to www.newdomain.de

Comment: This would have worked, if Shopware wasn't so mean.
I ended up with only blocking the root (it was the only page in use, we just need the shop for our licences). Shopware itself uses so many redirects, it ended up blocking a core file every time.